# how to make dynamic tables in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have the knowledge to create a form in angular 9.

```
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    this.form = this.fb.group({
       name: [null, [Validators.required]],
       description: [null, []],
       length: [0, [Validators.required]],
       precision: [0, [Validators.required]],
       type: [0, [Validators.required]],
    });
```

the code above would make a simple form like the one below

[image: simple form]

Right now I want to make a dynamic form, which is composed of multiple lines of the simple form above. So the user can add / remove one line of simple form.

[image: dynamic form]

I think it needs to apply the methods like addControl and removeControl in the FormBuilder class in angular but how to specific implement it

Comment: what about using `FormArray` instead of `FormGroup`? You can use `.push()` and `.removeAt()` methods.

Comment: if FormArray can have it work, that is ok for me

Comment: yes, let me create one example with `FormArray`

Comment: https://angular-forms-formarray-example-qtu68o.stackblitz.io

Comment: here is the simple reproduction example. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **FormGroup** should contain a **FormArray** and in this one, you have to add controls as you described.

So, first of all you have to change your form declaration like this:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    entries: this.formBuilder.array([]);
 });
```

And in this way, you will be able to add/remove controls.

You can define a method which will return a **FormGroup** of your type:

```
createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
       name: [null, [Validators.required]],
       description: [null, []],
       length: [0, [Validators.required]],
       precision: [0, [Validators.required]],
       type: [0, [Validators.required]],
   })
}
```

Then you have to define some methods to add/remove a **FormGroup** to/from **FormArray**:

```
addFormGroup(): void {
   this.formEntries.push(this.createFormGroup());
}

deleteFormGroup(index: number): void {
   this.formEntries.removeAt(index);
}

get formEntries(): FormArray {
   return this.form.controls.entries as FormArray;
}
```

In the **HTML** you have to list each **FormGroup** from your **FormArray**:

```
<button (click)="addFormGroup()"> ADD </button>

<form [formGroup]="form">
   <div formArrayName="entries">
      <div *ngFor="let entry of formEntries.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <!-- add each FormControl -->

        <button (click)="deleteFormGroup(i)"> DELETE </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```